# How do I pass indexPath (not indexPath.row) into my IBAction for my UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, ibaction

I am developing a to-do application. In my app, I press a checkbox button to delete a row. I write this code in order to pass the indexPath.row into my checkbox button:

```
cell.checkbox.tag = indexPath.row
cell.checkbox.addTarget(self, action: "checkAction:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
```

The first code allows me access to indexPath.row and the second one allow me to create a function for when my button is pressed. This is the function I use for when the button is pressed:

```
@IBAction func checkAction(sender: UIButton) {
    taskMgr.removeTask(sender.tag)
    tblTasks.reloadData()
}
```

Now, I want to add animation for when it deletes, so it doesn't look so sudden. The code I would use is this:

```
tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Automatic)
```

However, I only have access to indexPath.row in my checkAction function. How do I get access to the indexPath (without sacrificing indexPath.row)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tags can give you an erroneous row if you move rows around or add or delete rows until you reload the entire table. So, instead of using tags, you can use `indexPathForRowAtPoint:` in your button method to get the `indexPath`.

```
@IBAction func checkAction(sender: UIButton) {

    let point = sender.convertPoint(CGPointZero, toView: self.tableView)
    let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForRowAtPoint(point)
    taskMgr.removeTask(indexPath.row)
    tblTasks.reloadData()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can save the indexPath in the view controller:

```
class ViewController: UITableViewController {

    var toDeletedIndexPath: NSIndexPath?

    @IBAction func checkAction(sender: UIButton) {
        var cell = sender
        do {
            cell = cell.superview
        } while cell.isKindOfClass(UITableViewCell)

        self.toDeletedIndexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForCell(cell)

        tblTasks.reloadData()
    }
}
```

then

```
tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([self.toDeletedIndexPath], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Automatic)
```

Comment: This is dangerous. Different versions of iOS can have differing numbers of views between the button and the cell.

Answer (score 0):

If you have only one section in table view than I would suggest you to assign tag to the instance of `UIButton` and the tag value should be equal to the `indexPath.row`

But if you have more than one section and you need to access `index path` than in the touch event of the button via sender than I think you should subclass `UIButton` and add `NSIndexPath` attribute. When you create instance of `Custom UIButton` then assign index path to the `index path` attribute of the `custom button instance`. Now when the button is clicked you can access the index path as it is the attribute of `Custom UIButton`.